# VieleRETS and Rapattoni RETS Server

Tags: web, port, rets

I am using vieleRETS as RETS client. I have all the information regarding Rapattoni RETS server such as userID, password and Agent-header.

I have requested the ISP to open up the port 6103. The support team conformed the port is open. The website is hosted on a shared hosting.

As per my request the tech monitored the HTTP request on port 6103. There is no activity on that port.

I checked the RETS server with firewall_check.php within the vieleRETS extras folder.
it works. but the same test on the website failed with the following error.

FAILURE ERRNO 111 ERRSTR Connection refused

My question is if the port 6103 open on web server, will it return success?

This is the code that checks . . .

```
set_time_limit(0);
$socket = @fsockopen($address, $port, $errno, $errstr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Rapattoni support is best in the west (everywhere actually, but that doesn't rhyme). It always helps if you can provide a an http capture from wire shark or fiddler .  Make sure that your MLS hasn't put an IP filter on your setup.  Also make sure that you are selecting version 1.7.2...  It's been some months that I've been out of the RETS game, but I'm sure Tony will get you up and running...  Rets@rapattoni.com should be your POC